# How to use NASA's panoply on Windows system?

Tags: java-9

I want to use Panoply on my computer (Windows 10).

The packages I downloaded from [this website](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) said that it requires JAVA 9 (or later version) to install Panoply. But my JAVA version (JAVA 8) on my computer can not be renewed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIFOw.png)

So my questions is how to install JAVA 9 correctly on Windows.

Comment: Did you remove the Java 8 installation from your computer? Did you install Java 9? If you installed Java 9, did you update the PATH environment variable?

Comment: “But I can't” is not a real problem description.